# The type JList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Tags: java, windows, swing, jbuilder

I have a project that runs in eclipse on linux, i have moved a copy of it to jbuilder on windows and have run into a few issues.

I get the following error:

```
The type JList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
```

for this line of code:

```
private JList<String> songListView;
```

I have various other issues all of which seem to be related to swing.
Is there a particular library i need to import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JList was not retrofitted with generics until Java SE 7.

You must still be using Java SE 6.

Comment: think you are right unfortunately it is not my machine and am not able to just update it.

Answer (score 1):

Generics were introduced to the `JList` class in Java 7. You are most likely using JDK version 6 or under. Upgrade to JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

[Generic Jlist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) introduced in JDK 7 while in case of [older version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) this feature was not availible.

Point your eclipse to JDK 7 and your issue will be resolved.